# Can I debug a module function in PyCharm Python console?

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I have a module `bar` that defines a function `foo`. I can use PyCharm console to call this function:

```
import bar
bar.foo()
```

Is it possible to make PyCharm *debug* the code during such code, i.e. stop at breakpoints?

If it matters, I am using PyCharm on Windows.

Comment: Try Shift+f9 to start debugging. f9 to jump to the next break-point.  More info on the web...

Comment: AFAIK, Shift+F9 simply starts debugging, contrary to Shift+F10, which runs it with debugging disabled. I am looking for a way to call one specific function from the module with debugging enabled.

Comment: I would appreciate a comment related to down-voting, to help me learn.

Comment: @texnic, I am not someone who down-voted this, but I can guess why. Your question is not programming related; it is a question about how to use a particular program's user interface. So it doesn't fit this site's purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you just need to define main function to call `bar.foo()`:

```
import bar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar.foo()
```